# Python3: Whats difference between these 2 calculations about integer divide

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code

```
a = [10,10,20]
b = [2,5,4]
print(sum(a) / sum(b))
print(sum([i/j for i,j in zip(a,b)])/3)
```

The output is

```
3.6363636363636362
4.0
```

My question is: How to make the first calculation right.And why is there such a difference?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "how to make the first calculation right" mean? What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

The first one is `(10+10+20)/(2+5+4) = 40/11 = 3.6363`.

The second one is `(10/2 + 10/5 + 20/4)/3 = (5 + 2 + 5)/3=4`

Those are two different calculations. There is no reason to assume there should not be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the calculation. 
In the first case i.e, in

(print(sum(a) / sum(b)))

you are first adding the numerator and adding the denominator seperately and then dividing them
let [a,b,c] and [d,e,f] be your list elements, in the first case, you are doing

```
(a+b+c)/(d+e+f)
```

While in the second case, you are doing

```
a/d + b/e + c/f
```

and then dividing by 3
Which is why you got two different answers